# Setting up XFCE profiles

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, xfce

I was wondering if there's a way to set a profile before logging into my account. Like, let's say: My session starts running certain start up programs like Skype, Thunderbird or even Pidgin, which I allowed myself. Now, I'm traveling and I have to use my laptop in a place with no WiFi Connection. So with no Internet, I want to have the ability to say to it "Ok PC, there's no WiFi or available connection, start the session in this profile so Don't load the usual programs".

I know that I can do some scripts for that, but I'd like to know if there's an existent software doing that. If it exists for XFCE, what's its name? Would you recommend it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **`NetworkManager`**?

*NetworkManager* has a feature called **dispatcher**.

Place scripts in the directory `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`

You can use this script to determine if you are connected. Save it to `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/wifi-profile` as root.

```
#!/bin/bash
wifistatus=$(iwgetid -r);
if [ ! -z "$wifistatus" ]; then
   pidgin &
   skype &
fi
```

Make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/wifi-profile
```

Note: iwgetid depends on the **wireless_tools** package.

Comment: Interesting answer, I'll check that out and give feedback.